# How to draw nodes with equal sizes, regardless label value/length?

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes

I would like to make 12 nodes with same sized circles. 
Currently, the radius of a circle for single digit number and two digit numbers are different. 
Let `r1` be the radius for single digit numbers. 
Let `r2` be the radius for two digit numbers. 
How can I make all numbers to have circles with radius `r1`?

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[graphics, tightpage, active]{preview}
\setlength{\PreviewBorder}{2pt}
\PreviewEnvironment{tikzpicture}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.5]
    \begin{scope}[auto, every node/.style={draw,circle},node distance=2cm]
    % the vertices
    \node(v1) at (0,0){1};
    \node[above=of v1](v2){2};
    \node[above=of v2](v3){3};
    \node[right=of v1](v4){4};
    \node[above=of v4](v5){5};
    \node[above=of v5](v6){6};
    \node[right=of v4](v7){7};
    \node[above=of v7](v8){8};
    \node[above=of v8](v9){9};
    \node[right=of v7](v10){10};
    \node[above=of v10](v11){11};
    \node[above=of v11](v12){12};

    \draw (v1)--(v2)
    (v2)--(v3)
    (v1)--(v4)
    (v2)--(v5)
    (v3)--(v6)
    (v4)--(v7)
    (v5)--(v8)
    (v6)--(v9)
    (v7)--(v10)
    (v8)--(v11)
    (v9)--(v12)
    (v10)--(v11)
    (v11)--(v12);

    \end{scope}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Clarification: You want the bigger nodes to have the same radius as the smaller ones? Is `r1` actually given or do you want to get that from the small nodes?

Answer (score 18):

you can specify a minimum size in style and if necessary restrict inner sep

```
 \documentclass[11pt,tikz,border=2pt]{standalone}
    \usetikzlibrary{positioning}
    \begin{document}
     \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.5]
      \begin{scope}[auto, every node/.style={draw,circle,minimum size=2em,inner sep=1},node distance=2cm]
        % the vertices
        \node(v1) at (0,0){1};
        \node[above=of v1] (v2) {2};
        \node[above=of v2] (v3) {3};
        \node[right=of v1] (v4) {4};
        \node[above=of v4] (v5) {5};
        \node[above=of v5] (v6) {6};
        \node[right=of v4] (v7) {7};
        \node[above=of v7] (v8) {8};
        \node[above=of v8] (v9) {9};
        \node[right=of v7 ,] (v10) {10};
        \node[above=of v10] (v11) {11};
        \node[above=of v11,] (v12) {12};
      \end{scope}
     \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 15):

The easiest way would be to use an invisible digit in the node and a label placed at the center with the actual text.

### Code

```
\documentclass[11pt,tikz,border=2pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.5]
  \begin{scope}[auto, every node/.style={draw,circle},node distance=2cm]
    % the vertices
    \node(v1) at (0,0){1};
    \node[above=of v1] (v2) {2};
    \node[above=of v2] (v3) {3};
    \node[right=of v1] (v4) {4};
    \node[above=of v4] (v5) {5};
    \node[above=of v5] (v6) {6};
    \node[right=of v4] (v7) {7};
    \node[above=of v7] (v8) {8};
    \node[above=of v8] (v9) {9};
    \node[right=of v7 , label=center:10] (v10) {\phantom{0}};
    \node[above=of v10, label=center:11] (v11) {\phantom{0}};
    \node[above=of v11, label=center:12] (v12) {\phantom{0}};
  \end{scope}
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: As all digits have the same height you can also simply use `\clap{}` on the label text, like `\node[above=of v11] (v12) {\clap{12}};`

Comment: @TomBombadil Which definition of `\clap` do you use? The width of a single digit is still needed: [`\def\clap#1{\makebox[\widthof{0}]{#1}}`](http://i.stack.imgur.com/WaCNM.png). `\clap` from `mathtools` doesn’t give [the best results](http://i.stack.imgur.com/KNi9i.png). (In both cases, I added `\fbox`es around the text of nodes `9` to `12`.)

Answer (score 8):

I guess the easiest/least hacky way is to make use of `/tikz/minimum size`

Just replace this line

```
\begin{scope}[auto, every node/.style={draw,circle},node distance=2cm]
```

with this

```
\begin{scope}[auto, every node/.style={draw,circle,minimum size=1cm},node distance=2cm]
```

**Code**:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[graphics, tightpage, active]{preview}
\setlength{\PreviewBorder}{2pt}
\PreviewEnvironment{tikzpicture}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}
        \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.5]
        \begin{scope}[auto, every node/.style={draw,circle,minimum size=1cm},node distance=2cm]

        % the vertices
        \node(v1) at (0,0){1};
        \node[above=of v1](v2){2};
        \node[above=of v2](v3){3};
        \node[right=of v1](v4){4};
        \node[above=of v4](v5){5};
        \node[above=of v5](v6){6};
        \node[right=of v4](v7){7};
        \node[above=of v7](v8){8};
        \node[above=of v8](v9){9};
        \node[right=of v7](v10){10};
        \node[above=of v10](v11){11};
        \node[above=of v11](v12){12};

        \draw (v1)--(v2)
        (v2)--(v3)
        (v1)--(v4)
        (v2)--(v5)
        (v3)--(v6)
        (v4)--(v7)
        (v5)--(v8)
        (v6)--(v9)
        (v7)--(v10)
        (v8)--(v11)
        (v9)--(v12)
        (v10)--(v11)
        (v11)--(v12);

        \end{scope}
        \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**Output**:

[image]

Comment: ...and of course `inner sep` as pointed out by @rpapa

Answer (score 0):

A PSTricks solution:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{multido}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage{xfp}

% parameters
\def\width{4}
\def\height{3}
\def\radius{0.3}
\def\distance{1} % \distance > 2*\radius

\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}(-\radius,-\radius)(\fpeval{\distance*(\width-1)+\radius},\fpeval{\distance*(\height-1)+\radius})
  \multido{\rA = 0+\distance, \iA = 1+1}{\height}{%
    \multido{\rB = 0+\distance, \iB = \iA+1, \iC = \iA+\height}{\width}{%
      \rput(\rB,\rA){\pscircle(0,0){\radius}}
      \rput(\rB,\rA){$\iC$}}}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: output1]

If you want the numbering to be horizontal, you can do the following:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{multido}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage{xfp}

% parameters
\def\width{4}
\def\height{3}
\def\radius{0.3}
\def\distance{1} % \distance > 2*\radius

\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}(-\radius,-\radius)(\fpeval{\distance*(\width-1)+\radius},\fpeval{\distance*(\height-1)+\radius})
  \multido{\rA = 0+\distance, \iA = 1+1}{\width}{%
    \multido{\rB = 0+\distance, \iB = \iA+1, \iC = \iA+\width}{\height}{%
      \rput(\rA,\rB){\pscircle(0,0){\radius}}
      \rput(\rA,\rB){$\iC$}}}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: output2]

All you have to do is change the values of the parameters and the drawing will by adjusted accordingly.